# Trying to insert php inside php

Tags: php, string

I've tried to use double quotes and single quotes with this php string. However, with no success. How can I call php within php?

```
<?php echo wpws_get_content('<?php the_field('rate_my_professor_link''); ?>','.comment','html','user_agent=Bot+at+mysite.com&on_error=error_show&')?>
```

Comment: Wait, what are you trying to accomplish? You cannot nest `<?php ?>`.

Comment: Just pass the function into the outer function as a param: `echo wpws_get_content(the_field('rate_my_professor_link'),'.comment','html'....);`

Comment: I'm pretty sure doing that would open up a rip in the space-time continuum.

Answer (score 4):

You just need to do this:

```
<?php echo wpws_get_content(the_field('rate_my_professor_link'), '.comment', 'html', ''user_agent=Bot+at+mysite.com&on_error=error_show&'); ?>
```

You can put functions directly into other functions.

Comment: Unfortunately this solution does not work. I had tried that before. :(

Comment: Well then something is wrong with the `the_field()` function; it may not be returning the correct data. However, I really think that something is wrong with the arguments in the `wpws_get_content()` function because of the complexity of the arguments. Try and isolate and simply the script.

Comment: the field argument works fine separately. The problem is that somehow the css of the page gets affected if I type the php in that manner. What I'm trying to go do is get a link from a wordpress custom field and put in the function above.

Comment: Just do this: `$field = the_field('rate_my_professor_link');` and then `echo wpws_get_content($field, '.comment',......);`

Comment: I think your answer is a good partial answer. I think I should get the custom field value first and than use your solution.